# should I replace slightly broken iron toilet flange or switch to new ABS

Tags: toilet, flange, cast-iron

I'm replacing the sub-flooring and will be tiling. I know that the toilet flange will be low, and it is chipped on one side where the toilet bolts go. I see two options (there could be more...):

1. leave it alone and once the tile is complete, get a repair plate and build up to correct height.
2. since there is a stainless sleeve easy to access, replace the complete section and set to correct height before buttoning up the floor

Is there an obvious answer here? I don't see a problem leaving it alone, but I don't want to regret it! Here is a picture:
[image]

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 2, definitely.

Height issues aside, a damaged flange gives a high risk of loose toilet syndrome, which turns into leaky toilet syndrome, which turns into angry spouse syndrome when you have to re-tile.

Comment: Completely agree, now is the time to replace it. Also, height issues **not** aside, a ring at the proper height (flush with the finished floor) also reduces chances of compromised wax seal, i.e. compromised spousal relationship.

Comment: ok - I did the right thing. It took 10 minutes to remove it. It's a 3x4 16" cast iron pipe with the toilet flange sweated on. I'm not sure what to expect at depot. I'm hoping the ABS is 2 pieces or something very similar. I'd appreciate any comments on what to expect ABS-wise. Thanks for supporting choice #2 and for the proactive marital therapy!

Comment: You'll end up with another coupler to go from cast to abs; 2 sections of pipe and an elbow. Perfect world would include a bit of framing to screw the flange to. This could be as simple as a couple of 2x4s across the existing framing.